# sql error#1064 no idea what is wrong here

Tags: mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE Products( Category VARCHAR(30), Item VARCHAR(30),PRIMARY KEY, Pr' at line 2

```
   CREATE TABLE Products(
   Category VARCHAR(30),
   Item VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
   Price DECIMAL(5,2),
   Quantity INT
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: i even deleted the guts of the table and still got the error its saying theres a prob with the create table part maybe { instead of ( idk

Comment: YOu aren't trying to execute this inside a PHP mysql_query() call, where it is chained with multiple `CREATE TABLE` statements, are you?

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
Category VARCHAR(30),
Item VARCHAR(30),PRIMARY KEY, <-- The comma is your problem
Price DECIMAL(5,2),
Quantity INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To assign PK to a column, it should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
Category VARCHAR(30),
Item VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
Price DECIMAL(5,2),
Quantity INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You're doing something else wrong then. [It works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59c9e) for me.

Comment: The error is reported at `CREATE TABLE`, so my bet is on something like trying to execute multiple CREATE statements in one API call like mysql_query()...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Valid thought. Or a previous statement not being terminated `;`.